# Set field Originator Signature to Current User

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Good day, I have a SharePoint form the has a Originator Completed Dropdown with Yes or No as options. If the dropdown is yes, I would like to use JavaScript to set the OriginatorSignature (Text Field) to the loginName or current user. Can someone assist with this function?

```html
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>  
$(document).ready(function () {  
GetUserLogin();  
});  
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;  
function GetUserLogin() {  
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";  
var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };  
$.ajax({  
  url : requestUri,  
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",  
  headers : requestHeaders,  
  success : QuerySuccess,  
  error : QueryError  
});  
}  
function QuerySuccess(data, request){  
  var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];  
  $("input[title='Originator Signature']").val(loginName);  
}  
function QueryError(error) {  
  alert(error);  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: I have the above to get user info but if Originator Completed Dropdown equals yes then I Would like Originator Signature to populate the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("select[title='Originator Completed Dropdown']").val()=="Yes"){
        GetUserLogin();
    }
    $("select[title='Originator Completed Dropdown']").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Yes"){
            GetUserLogin();
        }else{
            $("input[title='Originator Signature']").val("");
        }
    });
});
function GetUserLogin(){
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + ")",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var loginName = data.d.LoginName;
            if(loginName.indexOf("|")!=-1){
                loginName = loginName.split('|')[1];
            }
            $("input[title='Originator Signature']").val(loginName);    
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```